# Comparing two columns from two data frames with different numbers of rows [R]

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frames :

```
df1 <- data.frame(row.names=1:4, id=c(1, 2, 3, 4), var2=c(10,20,30,40))
df2 <- data.frame(row.names=1:3, id=c(1, 2, 4), var2=c(10,20,40))
```

I am looking for a command to compare the `id` columns of the two data frames and return the row.names of the records that are missing in the second data frame:
I would appreciate it if you could help me with this.

Comment: Look at the `%in%` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at `%in%`:

```
> which(!df1$id %in% df2$id)
[1] 3
> rownames(df1[!df1$id %in% df2$id, ])
[1] "3"
> df1[!df1$id %in% df2$id, ]
  id var2
3  3   30
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try,

```
df1 <- data.frame(row.names=1:4, id=c(1, 2, 3, 4), var2=c(10,20,30,40))
df2 <- data.frame(row.names=1:3, id=c(1, 2, 4), var2=c(10,20,40))    
row.names(df1[!df1$id %in% df2$id,])
```